# Fetching the pattern for input for the string using re.sub

Tags: python, regex, whitespace

I downloaded a file as a .csv then changed the ',' to '|'and some of the strings in the file have leading white space. Since it's a file I can't (or can't figure out how to) use str.strip() because the whitespace is not leading the entire file. Right now I'm trying to use

```
re.sub('\|\s(.+?)\|','\|.+?\|',file)
```

where the second argument is supposed to be the original pattern, just with the single space stripped away. However, it's returning "\|.+?\|" in my file instead of the original text. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a backreference, The backreference `\1` references the first capturing group.

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\|)\s+(.*?)(?=\||$)', '\\1', file)
```

**Explanation**:

```
(?<=         # look behind to see if there is:
  \|         #   '|'
)            # end of look-behind
\s+          # whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
(            # group and capture to \1:
  .*?        #   any character except \n (0 or more times)
)            # end of \1
(?=          # look ahead to see if there is:
  \|         #   '|'
 |           #  OR
  $          #   before an optional \n, and the end of the string
)            # end of look-ahead
```